Как отправить письмо по почте (@gmail.com) с помощью C++?
Для проекта в котором я участвую, нужна авторизация с помощью почты. То есть пользователь регистрируется, вводит почту, все эти данные скармливаются программе, и та уже должна отправить сгенерированную ссылку на почту. Проблемы у меня начались только с отправкой.
Я пробовал многие способы, вот недавно набрел на этот вопрос
и нашел там ссылку на c++ curl (https://curl.se/libcurl/c/smtp-mail.html) библиотеку. Установил с помощью vcpkg, по стандарту. Но вот разобраться в примере не смог. Куда вставлять пароль от почты? Или OAuth Токен. Что за "CC_ADDR      "info@example.org"
Поэтому прошу вас написать, или скинуть ссылку на работающий пример отправки писем.
Актуальный*.
И желательно с комментариями.

У них все не так просто, там, кажется, надо еще зарегистрировать программу; просто сказать, что разрешаете использовать сторонние программы, недостаточно. Правда, я этим занимался давно, так что может что и изменилось.

Посмотрите еще вот этот вопрос и ссылки в нём: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449193/
